# Delay turn off relay

Tags: switches, relay, delay

I am an entry-level hobbyist. I am trying to find a delayed turn off relay for a light, but all the ones that I can find I don't understand how the switch fits into the equation.

Taking this relay as an example: [image: relay example]

The picture perfectly describes everything except for where the switch itself should be wired in. Obviously it's not on the incoming as that would switch on/off the entire thing, and obviously not on the load, as that would switch on/off only that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wow it has a pair of "voltage regulator tube"! And they're important enough to be labeled!! Must be some fine quality product there ...

Comment: i think that you are misunderstanding the device ..... i think that it turns off automatically after a delay when power is applied ...... flip the main power on, device runs for a while, then shuts off ..... turn off main power switch to reset ..... great for bathroom fans

Comment: What time period are you looking for?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are some solder pads on the back you had to connect to select the delay range. Another option would be you had to replace a resistor and/or cap or simply buy the correct version of that module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think with Jstola has "nailed" it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fphDqe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Connected like this switch 1 when left on will run the "delay off" program,
which is really time-limited on period.  To re-start the timer this switch must be turned off and back on.

switch 2 will light the lamp permanently.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiAACu.png)</sup>

Connected like this when the switch is tuned off the delay kicks in to keep the lamp burning for the period set. Unless you can find a make-before-break switch for this position there may be a flicker during the switch-over.  Turning the switch on powers the lamp directly, but cuts the power to the timing circuit, readying it to begin the delay-off perioon when the switch it thrown back to the off position.